# AngularJS slow when rendering large string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, usability

For my Angular 1.5 file upload component, I implemented a preview.

When the user selects a file, it is read by a `FileReader` and *on load end*, I store the content in a controller variable like

```
fileReader.onloadend = function(ev) {
    $rootScope.$evalAsync(function($scope) {
        $ctrl.rawFileContent = ev.target.result;
    });
};
```

The template shows it to the user

```
<pre ng-show="$ctrl.rawFileContent">{{$ctrl.rawFileContent}}</pre>
```

This worked pretty well for my test during development.

## The Problem

Real world users are going to upload >500kB files and then it takes minutes until the template is rendered.

Profiling showed, that some internal function in 'content-script.bundle.js' takes by far most of the time.

**Update:**
And worst of all ;) it has to run in IE11.

## What I tried so far

1. using one time binding `{{::$ctrl.rawFileContent}}` which yielded no improvement
2. fetching the `<PRE>` and setting its inner text via direct DOM manipulation, which still takes long and seemed a bit 'non-angulary' to me.

   ```
   <pre ng-show="$ctrl.rawFileContentReady" class="previewTarget"></pre>`


   $rootScope.$evalAsync(function($scope) {
       var previewTarget = document.getElementsByClassName("previewTarget")[0];
       previewTarget.innerHTML = ev.target.result;
   });
   ```

*Do you have any ideas, why this takes so long?*

*How can I speed it up?*

Or, as a workaround, can I track the progress somehow to inform the user?

Comment: I am still wondering how that preview of a 500k file looks like? it would be hundred of pages.

Comment: reading of file and showing it in front-end is making it slow or AngularJS binding?

Comment: Was curious how many lines there could be on a 500 KB text [file](http://www.sample-videos.com/download-sample-text-file.php). 1700 lines of text! Instead of trying to render everything you can use [infinite scroll](http://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/) to render just a part of the file.

Comment: Here you are a plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/Mc9IxScpu4BphccvblAU). I've tried what your scenario, but is taking a normal time considering that you are loading a big text file. Try to update and use this plunker for your question, maybe I'm not understanding something.

Comment: I want to handle log files, which _can_ get big. Users don't want to think about it and just throw them towards the (web-) app. The infinite scrolling approach looks promising...

Comment: First you really need analyze what problem is - reading file/displaying content/displaying content with Angular, these are totally different problems.

Answer (score -1):

[This link helps to find how to do progress](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/05/22/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-3/)

Comment: Please provide some explanation, how your link is relevant to my problem. Note, that my problem is _not_ the file loading but the rendering afterwards.

Comment: This helps to show progress while job is being done.